# Master thesis topics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, education

I'm studying a Master degree in condensed matter physics but I've been always interested by theoretical physics, especially QFT and now I need to do a master thesis for graduating and I'm looking for a topic in theoretical physics and I need help in listing potential topics

Comment: @AyoubEL-Armani find a supervisor and express your interests to them and work on what they have to offer you? You're usually given some options, but first you have to find and ask a supervisor.